# How do I limit threads created by JAX

Tags: jax

I am trying to reproduce the issue given over [here](https://github.com/google/jax/issues/16215). Despite following the steps given in the link the number of threads created by `JAX` stays the same.

Therefore, whether I do -

```
import os, subprocess as sp

os.environ["MKL_NUM_THREADS"]="1"
os.environ["OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS"]="1"
os.environ["OMP_NUM_THREADS"]="1"
os.environ["NUM_INTER_THREADS"]="1"
os.environ["NUM_INTRA_THREADS"]="1"
os.environ["XLA_FLAGS"]="--xla_cpu_multi_thread_eigen=false intra_op_parallelism_threads=1 --xla_force_host_platform_device_count=1"
print(os.sched_getaffinity(0))

import jax
print("pre:", int(sp.check_output(f"ls /proc/{os.getpid()}/task | wc -l", shell=True)))
jax.numpy.zeros([])
print("post:", int(sp.check_output(f"ls /proc/{os.getpid()}/task | wc -l", shell=True)))
```

or

```
import os, subprocess as sp

# os.environ["MKL_NUM_THREADS"]="1"
# os.environ["OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS"]="1"
# os.environ["OMP_NUM_THREADS"]="1"
# os.environ["NUM_INTER_THREADS"]="1"
# os.environ["NUM_INTRA_THREADS"]="1"
# os.environ["XLA_FLAGS"]="--xla_cpu_multi_thread_eigen=false intra_op_parallelism_threads=1 --xla_force_host_platform_device_count=1"
# print(os.sched_getaffinity(0))

import jax
print("pre:", int(sp.check_output(f"ls /proc/{os.getpid()}/task | wc -l", shell=True)))
jax.numpy.zeros([])
print("post:", int(sp.check_output(f"ls /proc/{os.getpid()}/task | wc -l", shell=True)))
```

I get the output as follows -

```
pre: 1
post: 44
```

I came across a relevant [post](https://github.com/google/jax/issues/15866) describing this problem. However, I don't understand the solution proposed by the OP.They said, "*The best solution would be one that let the user override the size of the main threadpool through environment variables.*"

Comment: if you're on a unix-like machine, try with taskset: `taskset --cpu-list 0 python test.py`. that will limit the command to the first cpu. in python, you can use `os.sched_setaffinity`

Comment: This does help reduce the thread count to 11. I was wondering if there's a more direct way of controlling thread count. Right now, we are controlling the CPUs being used.